# AVG in Sql - Float number problem

Tags: sql, average

```
SELECT     AVG(variable) AS Expr1, SUM(variable) AS Expr2
FROM       ......
```

result for AVG is 2, but it is not true, it must be 2.95. What is the problem, any idea?

Comment: What is the type of variable? I guess that it is an integer. Right?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Try

```
Select
    AVG(Cast(variable as Float)),
    SUM(variable)
From
    Table
```

Comment: I would suggest using decimal instead of float. See this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056323/difference-between-numeric-float-and-decimal-in-sql-server

Comment: @PouyaBCD Without knowing the precise use-case you can't just suggest to use decimals instead of floats. There exist perfectly valid use-cases for floats/doubles where using decimals would not work well (for example when you need huge ranges, for example numbers from 1e-18 to 1e+18).