# SQL Server AVG returning 0 for every row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to make a somewhat complex query on SQL Server. Had to do a select from a select in order to group by aliases. The problem is that the sum and the count return correct values, but the average returns always zero. if I calculate it as sum(quer.score)/count(quer.score) it also returns all zeros.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

```
SELECT quer.month, quer.item_type, SUM(quer.score) AS sum_values,COUNT(quer.score) as count_values, avg(quer.score) as final_value FROM (
SELECT
CASE
WHEN MONTH(inte.date) = 1 THEN 'January'
WHEN MONTH(inte.date) = 2 THEN 'February'
WHEN MONTH(inte.date) = 3 THEN 'March'
WHEN MONTH(inte.date) = 4 THEN 'April'
WHEN MONTH(inte.date) = 5 THEN 'May'
WHEN MONTH(inte.date) = 6 THEN 'June'
WHEN MONTH(inte.date) = 7 THEN 'July'
WHEN MONTH(inte.date) = 8 THEN 'Agosto'
WHEN MONTH(inte.date) = 9 THEN 'September'
WHEN MONTH(inte.date) = 10 THEN 'October'
WHEN MONTH(inte.date) = 11 THEN 'November'
WHEN MONTH(inte.date) = 12 THEN 'December'
END AS month,

CASE
    WHEN  inte.item_id in (SELECT distinct item_id from Items where item_type = 'electronic') THEN 'electronic'
    ELSE 'not electronic'
END AS item_type,

CASE WHEN scores.score <7 THEN -1
WHEN scores.score >8 THEN 1
ELSE 0
END AS score
FROM internal_items inte inner join scores_data scores on inte.item_id = scores.item_id
WHERE inte.internal_type = 'dba'
) quer

GROUP BY quer.month, quer.item_type
```

Result:

```
month     item_type           sum  count  avg
January   electronic           0     3     0
January   not electronic      -2     7     0
February  electronic          -4     6     0
February  not electronic      -6     8     0
March     electronic          -4     5     0
March     not electronic      -3     6     0
```

Comment: If `score` is an `int` then an `int` will be returned. I *assume* the average is less than `1` and greater than `-1` and hence represented as `0`. You'll need to cast the value to an appropriate decimal *before* you average it.

Comment: Also, your `CASE` expression looks odd; it will return zero for either 8 or NULL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AVG in Sql - Float number problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102406/avg-in-sql-float-number-problem)

Comment: Yes! You all are right! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should  use decimals or floats, not integers as data type, e. g. use

```
CASE WHEN scores.score <7 THEN -1.0
WHEN scores.score >8 THEN 1.0
ELSE 0.0
END AS score
```

(note the `.0` added).

SQL Server uses the same data type as the base column for the aggregate result, and thus, the average would be calculated as int when the input values are `int`s.