# cast varchar to float to bigint

Tags: t-sql, casting, varchar, bigint

I am trying to cast varchar to bigint. Then inserting it into an int column. I found that I am not getting expected value. Then I tried the following statements:

```
DECLARE @varData VARCHAR(50)

SET @varData  = '0000019.33'

select cast(@varData *cast(100 as float) as bigint)

select cast(@varData *cast(100 as float) as varchar)

select cast(cast(@varData *cast(100 as float) as varchar) as float)
```

Results:

```
1932

1933

1933
```

I am not able to understand why this difference is coming. But when I change the value to `0000029.33` then there is no difference in results.

I am stuck and do not have any idea why it's so happening. Help needed..!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please see this [Difference between numeric,float and decimal in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056323/difference-between-numeric-float-and-decimal-in-sql-server)

For you question, you should try CAST @vardata as numeric, like this

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(@varData AS numeric(27,9)) * 100  AS bigint)
```

Answer (score 1):

it happens because sql round the data, so lets say if u pick the wrong integer instead of 2.97 u will get 3.
now try to imagine how much data will be lost if u want to convert just 0.000002 :)
hope u understand better now

```
DECLARE @varData VARCHAR(50),
        @float float,
        @bigint bigint

SET @varData  = '0000019.33'    
set @bigint = convert ( bigint, (convert ( float, @vardata )) )
print @bigint
--or
set @float= convert ( float, @vardata )
set @bigint=convert ( bigint, @float)
print @bigint
```

Comment: I changed the value to '0000019.73', I got 1973, no rounding. Similarly for '0000029.33', I get, 2933 for all queries.

Comment: the data is not lost while ur changing the numbers u can switch even to 0000000000000000000029.29
the lost happen when ur converting the variables for example

declare @ck int 
set @ck=1.56
select cast(@ck as varchar)