# SQL Server SELECT Statement to exactly match latitude and longitude values held in a float data type

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select

I have a table with latitude and longitude stored as a float. I am needing a SELECT statement to match each latitude and longitude directly as I will be 'looking up' and inserting a postcode against each record. The table looks like the below

```
+-----------+-----------+------------------+--------------------+
|   Name    | LocatorID |     Latitude     |     Longitude      |
+-----------+-----------+------------------+--------------------+
| THE ALLEY |         1 | 52.2007179260254 | 0.39888408780098   |
| THE ALLEY |         2 | 52.5201377868652 | -2.13742804527283  |
| THE ALLEY |         3 | 51.0303649902344 | -1.90383625030518  |
| THE ALLEY |         4 | 50.9091453552246 | -0.537165105342865 |
+-----------+-----------+------------------+--------------------+
```

I would have thought the select statement would be something like:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [Name]
      ,[LocatorID]
      ,[Latitude]
      ,[Longitude]
  FROM [UKStreetsAndPlaces].[dbo].[OS_Locator]
  WHERE [Latitude] = 52.2007179260254
  AND [Longitude] = 0.39888408780098
```

However this returns NO results and I see many articles suggesting this approach is not appropriate.

The thing is, as you can see, I really do need an accurate match to ensure I insert the right postcode against the right record.

Comment: This is a typical precision problem that is inherent to the way that SQL Server stores values of type `float` internally. I would suggest storing `Latitude` and `Longitude` as `decimal`.

Comment: If you need accuracy stop using float. It is an approximate datatype and not all values can accurately be stored. You should instead use NUMERIC.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: I recommend reading the previous question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056323/difference-between-numeric-float-and-decimal-in-sql-server]

Comment: OK @JohnSaunders. I'm just not used to being so curt - especially when people are helping - it feels alien not to thank anyone in advance, but fair enough.

Comment: So, what if you thank people in advance for help, and nobody helps?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos. If you post an answer suggesting I should store the data as decimal I can accept this as the Answer. This was the solution that worked best for me in this case.

Comment: @Chris Glad I was able to help. I have posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical precision problem that is inherent to the way that SQL Server stores values of type `FLOAT` internally.

According to [**MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx) `FLOAT` and `REAL` are:

> *Approximate-number* data types for use with floating point numeric
>   data. Floating point data is approximate; therefore, *not all values in
>   the data type range can be represented exactly*.

I would suggest storing Latitude and Longitude as `DECIMAL`.

Comment: This is the solution that worked best for me. I followed a commonly recommended precision of Decimal(9,6) for storing the latitude and longitude points.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to case your lat/long as a decimal and do the compare?

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [Name]
    ,[LocatorID]
    ,[Latitude]
    ,[Longitude]
FROM [UKStreetsAndPlaces].[dbo].[OS_Locator]
WHERE CONVERT(DECIMAL(28,14), [Latitude]) = 52.2007179260254
AND CONVERT(DECIMAL(28,14), [Longitude]) = 0.39888408780098
```

Comment: Interesting... I did just try this but my latitude and longitude values all have different precisions and I noticed the CONVERT had to be exact (i.e. CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,6),Longitude) = 0.3988841 would not work but CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,7),Longitude) = 0.3988841 would). I found that converting the entire table fields from a float type to decimal type with a precision of 6,9 gave me the consistency and accuracy I need.

Comment: so then, you could just change the 28,14 to 6,9.  would that work?

Comment: It worked on values that were exactly 9,6 (e.g. 152.454384) but not if the precision was different (e.g. 8,6 such as 52.454384).

Answer (score 0):

FLOAT is an approximate datatype and it could couse the difference. Try to do it in that way for exmaple:

```
    CREATE TABLE #TMP
    (
     id int,
     lat decimal(20,15),
     long decimal(20,15),
    )

    INSERT INTO #TMP (id, lat, long) VALUES (1, 52.2007179260254, 0.39888408780098)
                                          , (2, 52.5201377868652, -2.13742804527283)
                                          , (3, 51.0303649902344, -1.90383625030518)
                                          , (4, 50.9091453552246, -0.537165105342865)


    select * from #TMP WHERE lat = 52.2007179260254
      AND long = 0.39888408780098
```