# SQL Rounding/Truncation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Something seems off with the SQL ROUND function.
I need to truncate some numbers at the second decimal place.  This is very straightforward using the ROUND function described here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003(SQL.90).aspx

I haven't done extensive testing.  But I have tried this on SQL Server 2008 R2 and 2012.  It seems to work great for almost every number I have tried except for 2.8  It always returns 2.79.  2.9 returns 2.9, 2.4 returns 2.4.  But 2.8 is off.  This is when I use a REAL.
If I change the data type to FLOAT then 2.4 returns 2.39 and 2.9 returns 2.89.
I have no idea why.  What am I missing?

See sample code below.
Putting on asbestos underwear as I'm sure I'm missing something obvious

```
DECLARE @x AS REAL

SELECT @x = 2.8

SELECT ROUND(@x,2,1) -- 2.79 WHAT?

SELECT @x = 2.8145

SELECT ROUND(@x,2,1) -- 2.81 OK

SELECT @x = 2.4

SELECT ROUND(@x,2,1) -- 2.4 OK

SELECT @x = 2.9

SELECT ROUND(@x,2,1) -- 2.9 OK

SELECT @x = 2.23954

SELECT ROUND(@x,2,1) -- 2.23 OK
```

Comment: Consider rounding in your application rather than in SQL.

Comment: That is the nature of floating point math.  If you want precision and scale use numeric or decimal and define precision and scale. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms187912(v=SQL.105).aspx  Float is approximate which works fine some of the time but not if you need precision and scale.  Prior post on SO about this-->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056323/difference-between-numeric-float-and-decimal-in-sql-server  Simply put... use the right data type and problem goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @x AS REAL, @y AS DECIMAL(10,2)

SELECT @x = 2.8 ,  @y = 2.8

SELECT ROUND(@x,2,1) [Real] , ROUND(@y,2,1) [Decimal]
```

Result:

```
Real    Decimal
2.79    2.80
```

The reason is the initial data types for variables, Real or Float are considered approximate data types , usually used to stored the imaginary number like Mass of earth , Distance to Mercury etc.

When using Float or Real data type(approximate data types) sql server sees 2.8 and 2.79 almost/approximately the same value hence the difference.

If you use the exact data types like Numeric or Decimal the precision is also taken into account hence the expected results.

Comment: you're not getting the desired result using `2.23954` unless the desired result is `2.24`

Comment: No the expected result would be `2.23` because you are truncating anything after two decimal places.

Comment: in your example just by setting `@y = 2.23954` converts it to 2.24.. the `Round(@y,2,1)` has no effect and still outputs 2.24

Comment: Just need to bump the scale of the DECIMAL up to 6 and it will truncate to 2.23 correctly.

Comment: well, 2.230000.  But I can handle the rest from there.

Comment: at least you taught us not to always trust `ROUND(numberic_expression, length, [function])` :)

Comment: @JamieD77 as I have mentioned in my answer with detail, when dealing with Decimal or Numeric data types precision has a very important role to play, as Tidge has already mentioned when you are assigning more decimal places to a variable you would need to extend the precision of your variable too, to get a precise answer hence the precision.

Comment: @JamieD77 no you can trust the function but always consider the data type too :)

Comment: extend the precision by 4 places more than you need?.. i dont see that in your answer at all

Comment: If tidge understands then that's all that matters