# SQL Server changing value of float

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I created console application where I'm using EF. I've got model where are some float variables. In my Database I also use FLOAT.

In c# I have got this value: 3,3
After insert it to my database there is value: 3,29999995231628

Why is it happening?

Comment: The `FLOAT` data type is not a precise data type. If you need exact precision then you should be using `DECIMAL` or `NUMERIC`

Comment: Add an answer so I will accept it. Thanks for info @TomH

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Decimal, Float and Double in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-net)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between numeric,float and decimal in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056323/difference-between-numeric-float-and-decimal-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `FLOAT` data type is not a precise data type. If you need exact precision then you should be using `DECIMAL` or `NUMERIC`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `FLOAT` is an approximate numeric datatype. You can use `DECIMAL` or `NUMERIC`, instead.

For detailed explanation, check this SO post:
[Difference between numeric, float and decimal in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056323/difference-between-numeric-float-and-decimal-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **real** instead of **float** and its true to save