# Loss scale when update table with multiply or divide numeric types in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, scale, precision, numeric

I have an application that user define formula based on other columns (e.g c=(a-b)*100/a ) then the application create SQL update query to calculate result (Types of all columns are NUMERIC). When the formula contains multiplication and division the result is not accurate. I know SQL Server truncates the scale to fit the result in multiplication and division.

1. [Difference between numeric, float and decimal in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056323/difference-between-numeric-float-and-decimal-in-sql-server)
2. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2006/03/29/multiplication-and-division-with-numerics/

But I am confused with below test. When I use variable or use formula in Select query the result is accurate but when I use formula in Update query the result is inaccurate!

```
--USE NUMERIC
CREATE TABLE TblTest
(
    a [numeric](18, 8) NULL,
    b [numeric](28, 15) NULL,
    c [numeric](28, 15) NULL    
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT TblTest (a, b)
VALUES (158.62700000, 155.000000000000000)

UPDATE TBlTest
SET c = (a - b) * 100 / a

SELECT a, b, c, (a-b) * 100 / a AS c2 
FROM TBlTest
```

Result: c=2.286495000000000 !!! and c2=2.286495993746

```
DECLARE @a AS NUMERIC(18, 8) = 158.62700000
DECLARE @b AS NUMERIC(28, 15) = 155.000000000000000
DECLARE @c AS NUMERIC(28, 15)

SELECT (@a - @b) * 100 / @a
```

Result: 2.286495993746

```
SELECT @c = (@a - @b) * 100 / @a
```

Result: 2.286495993746000

```
--USE FLOAT
CREATE TABLE TblTest2
(   
    a FLOAT(53) NULL,
    b FLOAT(53) NULL,
    c FLOAT(53) NULL    
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT TblTest2 (a, b)
VALUES (158.62700000, 155.000000000000000)

UPDATE TBlTest2
SET c = (a - b) * 100 / a

SELECT a, b, c, (a - b) * 100 / a AS c2 
FROM TBlTest2
```

Result: 2.28649599374634

Comment: just to clarify your question, please state what the correct value is and the incorrect value

Comment: SQL Server version? When I try your first example with 2012 SP1, I get the same value for `c` and `c2` (different scale though, which I suppose is interesting)

Comment: I get the same result as @AakashM

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2. Correct Value :2.286495993746 Incorrect Value :2.286495000000000