# On creating a table column of type "float with precision" column gets created as "real" type in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, types, sql-server-2016

I created a simple table as below:

```
create table table1
(
col1 float(1),
col2 float
)
```

When I check the table definition using sp_help or script table as create,
I get the float(1) as real

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table1](
[col1] [real] NULL,
[col2] [float] NULL
)
```

As per my understanding from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms173773.aspx) and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056323/difference-between-numeric-float-and-decimal-in-sql-server) references, float can have a precision n ranging from 1 to 53.

Why is it getting converted to real by default whenever float has a precision specified?

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server doesn't remember what language you used when you create the table - it just consults the current table definition and renders a piece of text that *could* have been used to create an identical table.

As the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx) points out, SQL Server doesn't support arbitrary precisions - it only supports two precisions - 24 and 53:

> SQL Server treats `n` as one of two possible values. If **1**<=n<=**24**, `n` is treated as **24**. If **25**<=n<=**53**, `n` is treated as **53**.

As it also points out, `real` is treated as a synonym for `float(24)`:

> The ISO synonym for **real** is **float(24)**.

So, any float column specified with a precision of 24 or lower will in fact be created as a `float(24)`. And a synonym for `float(24)` is `real`. The system doesn't remember whether it was originally specified as `float(1)`, `float(24)` or `real`.

---

> Why is it getting converted to real by default whenever float has a precision specified?

It doesn't. As per the above, if you create a column with type `float(25)` (or any higher precision), you'll find it gets returned as plain `float`, rather than `real`, because it was created as a `float(53)` and 53 is the default precision when none is supplied.