# Float stored as Real in database Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, precision, sqldatatypes

Why is `Float` stored as `Real` in `sys.columns` or `Information_schema.columns` when `precision <= 24`.

```
CREATE TABLE dummy
  (
     a FLOAT(24),
     b FLOAT(25)
  )
```

checking the data type

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME,
       COLUMN_NAME,
       DATA_TYPE,
       NUMERIC_PRECISION
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'dummy'
```

**Result:**

```
+------------+-------------+-----------+-------------------+
| TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | DATA_TYPE | NUMERIC_PRECISION |
+------------+-------------+-----------+-------------------+
| dummy      | a           | real      |                24 |
| dummy      | b           | float     |                53 |
+------------+-------------+-----------+-------------------+
```

So why is `float` stored as `real` when the `precision` is less than or equal to `24`. Is this documented somewhere ?

Comment: Very [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40398692/15498)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From an [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx) which discusses the difference between `float` and `real` in T-SQL:

> The ISO synonym for real is float(24).

```
float [ (n) ]
```

> Where n is the number of bits that are used to store the mantissa of the float number in scientific notation and, therefore, dictates the precision and storage size. If n is specified, it must be a value between 1 and 53. The default value of n is 53.

```
n value | Precision | Storage size
1-24    | 7 digits  | 4 bytes
24-53   | 15 digits | 8 bytes
```

> SQL Server treats n as one of two possible values. **If 1<=n<=24, n is treated as 24. If 25<=n<=53, n is treated as 53.**

As to why SQL Server labels it as `real`, I think it is just a synonym.  However, underneath the hood it is still a `float(24)`.

Comment: @Prdp I don't think it's storing it as `real`, but rather `float(24)`.  It is _labeling_ it as `real`.

Comment: Am comparing datatypes between two similar databases. This `Real` made me to go crazy because we don't create datatypes with `Real` :D. Later I realised that `Float` is what stored as `Real`

Answer (score 3):

> The ISO synonym for real is float(24).

```
Please refer for more info:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx
```

Comment: Thats ok but why is it storing as `Real` instead of `Float(24)`

Comment: Hi Pradeep, I think it is just a synonym.  The documentation makes it clear that underneath the hood it is still just a `float(24)`.