# Way of rounding of currency in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given the following values (`float` data type), I want to `ROUND` them in the following way:

```
+----------------+--------+
| Original Value | Result |
+----------------+--------+
| 53.36          | 53.40  |
| 53.34          | 53.30  |
| 53.35          | 53.35  |  --Do not round up when 5
+----------------+--------+
```

Is there is a way to do this using T-SQL?

Comment: `FLOAT` is notoriously susceptible to rounding errors - if you're working with currency and need precise values, I would strongly recommend using `DECIMAL(p,s)` instead !

Comment: Alright. thank you sir, @marc_s. :)

Comment: Why are you using float for currency?  Do you really need a range -1.79E+308 to -2.23E-308?   TSQL has a money data type.

Comment: The existing system is using that. I don't know why and I'm new to this system. @paparazzo :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need your value to remain `xx.x5` when found but [`ROUND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql) otherwise, the following will work for you:

([`IIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql) available in SQL Server 2012+)

```
DECLARE @val FLOAT = 53.35;
SELECT IIF ((RIGHT(@val,1) = 5), @val, ROUND(@val,1)) result

SET @val = 53.34
SELECT IIF ((RIGHT(@val,1) = 5), @val, ROUND(@val,1)) result

SET @val = 53.36
SELECT IIF ((RIGHT(@val,1) = 5), @val, ROUND(@val,1)) result
```

[image]

Here is a [good resource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7158770) to read about differences of types, specifically read about `float` types. Seems that's possibly not a good datatype for the values you have. Just something to consider.