# SUM(Column_Value) is giving a different value from calculator

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below are the column values in my sql table.When I add them up using a desktop calculator I get the sum as 0

[image]

But in sql when I take the sum of Item_Quantity, I am getting a strange value as below
[image]

The Data Type of this column is float. Can I please get some help on this? Thanks.

Comment: That's a float value, close to 0.

Comment: If you want to work with *precise decimal data*, then you've picked the wrong data type to represent it. What you're showing is a not unexpected result due to the fact that float cannot represent all *decimal* values precisely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: In case you're not familiar with the syntax, note that "-3.55E-15" means "-3.55 * 10 ^ -15", that is -0.00000000000000355

Comment: Basically you can change the column type to decimal if you need precise results. But keep in mind that decimal calculations are typically slower than float. I would suggest reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056323/difference-between-numeric-float-and-decimal-in-sql-server#7158770

Comment: @Nisarg, couldn't you cast the sum to decimal to get the speed of the FP operation but the precision of decimal? E.g., `SELECT CAST(-0.00000000000000355 AS decimal)` returns 0. I guess that's not really *precision* - more like rounding.

Comment: @Nisarg I have changed the Data Type to decimal(18,0) but its still not giving me 0, its giving me -2 instead

Comment: `decimal(18,0)` will not work as your data consists of decimal places, try `decimal(18,1)`

Comment: float numbers are represent as a binary number internally. E.g. `0.2` is binary `0.00110011001100110011...` with and infinite number of repetitions of `0011`, which, of course, have to be truncated in the computer. Therefore the small error you are seeing. See: [Decimal to Binary converter](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-binary.html)

Comment: Personally, with that specific data, I'd use `decimal(3,1)` there's no need to have a scale higher than 3 considering the highest/lowest values are `12.8` and `-16.6` respectively.

Comment: @Mazhar thanks, but your solution did not work, I am still getting the value as -2.0

Comment: @sumedha You should use `decimal(19, 4)` - i.e. precision of 19 digits where 4 of those digits come after the decimal point. If you are working with smaller numbers you can use `decimal(10, 4)`.

Comment: If you are still unable to get the expected result, I would suggest creating a [mcve]. Perhaps you can use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to create a working example.

Comment: If you changed the column type to 18,0 you possibly removed the decimals now all your data is wrecked.

Comment: Working example with `DECIMAL(18,1)`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/603c9/2

Comment: @DavidFaber: it *is* rounding -- without further specification, `DECIMAL` stands for `DECIMAL(18, 0)`, that is, you're just rounding to a number with no digits after the decimal point. Naturally that'll get you to 0, but it's not the data type you want to use for storage. (And not specifying precision and scale is a bad idea, because the rules for determining precision and scale when different values are combined are rather arcane -- being explicit helps in staving off surprises.)

Comment: See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bc23c/1/0

Comment: @IMSoP, Thanks, I restored the database and checked it again, doing this works! thanks for the example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you're saying using `DECIMAL(18,1)` will not work

Here's your sample data

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( Item_Quanity FLOAT)
INSERT INTO @t
(
    Item_Quanity
)
VALUES
(12.8) ,(-6.8) ,(1.4) ,(0.2) ,(3.4) ,(-2.8), (12) ,(-3.6) ,(-16.6)
```

Here's your query

```
SELECT SUM(Item_Quanity) FROM @t
```

which gives this result

```
(No column name)
-3.5527136788005E-15
```

Here's a modification of that query using `CAST`

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(Item_Quanity AS DECIMAL(18,1))) FROM @t
```

Which gives this result

```
(No column name)
0.0
```

Now changing the datatype from `FLOAT` to `DECIMAL(18,1)

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE ( Item_Quanity DECIMAL(18,1))
INSERT INTO @t1
(
    Item_Quanity
)
VALUES
(12.8) ,(-6.8) ,(1.4) ,(0.2) ,(3.4) ,(-2.8), (12) ,(-3.6) ,(-16.6) 

SELECT SUM(Item_Quanity)
FROM @t1
```

Which returns

```
(No column name)
0.0
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I restored the database again and checked, its working now.