# Unexpected results with double casting numeric datatype in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, types

I recently came across a weird case in an ETL process where the results seem unpredictable to me. I read [Difference between numeric, float and decimal in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1056323), but I don't think it's an overflow or decimal precision issue.

Scenario:

Source table "test" in SQL Server 2008 SP3, column a declared as numeric (38,6).

The result is cast first to real, and then to int. The issue doesn't occur if there is a direct cast from numeric to int.

Results of:

```
SELECT a,CAST(a as real) as real_a,CAST(CAST(a as real) as int) as int_a FROM test;
```

- a: 778881838.810000
- real_a: 7.78819E+08
- int_a: 778881856

The same experiment, run in SQL Server 2017 (**sql fiddle**) gives this:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/45aca/2

```
a: 778881838.81
real_a: 778881860
int_a: 778881856
```

I can (vaguely) understand the ..19E+08 case, but why is there a +18 difference in the double conversion case? The number seems completely arbitrary to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, first of all, the result in SQL Server 2017 for `real_a` is *not* `778881860`. It is `778881856`, exactly, just as in SQL Server 2008. How this floating-point value is presented by the *client* is another matter -- Management Studio shows me `7.788819E+08`, `sqlcmd` produces `7.7888186E+8`, and apparently SQL Fiddle uses another library altogether (one I would personally have issue with, seeing as how it obscures significant figures!)

This value is not arbitrary. `REAL` is a single-precision floating point type that cannot represent `778881838.81` exactly. The closest representable value is `778881856`, hence your result (the next lower representable value is `778881792`). Without casting to `INT`, you can see this value using

```
SELECT STR(CONVERT(REAL, CONVERT(NUMERIC(38, 6), 778881838.810000)), 40, 16)

778881856.0000000000000000
```

Your use of the term "double" makes me think you're confusing this with `FLOAT`, which is the double-precision floating point type. `FLOAT` cannot represent this value exactly either, but it comes much closer:

```
SELECT STR(CONVERT(FLOAT, CONVERT(NUMERIC(38, 6), 778881838.810000)), 40, 16)

778881838.8099999400000000
```

Converting this value to an `INT` yields the (truncated) `778881838`. (This truncation is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql#truncating-and-rounding-results) and does not happen for conversions to `NUMERIC`; you'll need to `ROUND` first before converting if you'd prefer `778881839` instead.)

Comment: Perfect. Can you add to your answer how is the representable value calculated so that I can accept it?

Comment: @pkExec: You mean, how we get from `778881838.810000` to the single-precision float value `778881856` as the closest value? I'd have to dig into the IEEE 754 standard for the details on that -- I can't claim to be an expert. If you enter the number on a site like [this](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html), you'll see the conversion (and the error). Click the `+` and `-` buttons to move forward/back on the exact values.

Answer (score 1):

Easy example for other people that want to test locally:

```
DECLARE  @test numeric (38,6)='778881838.810000'
SELECT @test as [Original],CAST(@test as real) as real_a,CAST(CAST(@test as real) as int) as int_a;

Original            real_a          int_a
778881838.810000    7.788819E+08    778881856
```

You would likely need someone from Microsoft to explain the way it works inside the SQL engine (and certainly to know why they made that decision), but I'll take a stab at the reasoning:

If the output is in scientific notation on the first cast and is then needed to cast to an int, it sets the int to the minimum value that would result in that scientific notation. It ends in 6 instead of 5 because rounding on 5 does not consistently round up on all cases ([Alternating tie-breaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding) for example).

But, no matter the reason, if precision is important, you should explicitly cast to  a numeric data type with a defined precision.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to convert from float or real to character data, using the STR string function is usually more useful than CAST( ). This is because STR enables more control over formatting. For more information, see STR (Transact-SQL) and Functions (Transact-SQL).

Please find the below links

[USE STR Instead of real](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

[STR example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/str-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
Use the below query : -

```
SELECT a,STR(a ,38,6) as real_a,CAST(CAST(a as real) as int) as int_a FROM test;
```

Please let me know if you find any issue.