# Error converting data type varchar to real SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I can not insert data into my table, I get an error when entering `real` data types, and I understand that the `real` data is a `double` in the sql server.
Why is it wrong, if I insert numbers of type `double`?

Stored Procedure:

[image]

Execute the Procedure:

[image]

Error After executing:
[image]

Comment: Note - we usually **much** prefer code to be in the question as *code*, not as images. We cannot copy & paste an image into our editors, and we don't need the typing practice. (It also excludes would-be answerers who use assistive technologies to access this site)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misusing the single quote signs. They should be used for string literals - not for numbers and definitely not for variables.

So what it boils down to is:

- you should use the variables as `@variable`
- you should pass string values with quote as `'string'`
- you should pass number values without quotes as `1.2345`

Therefore, your procedure should insert the values like this:

```
INSERT INTO DataImage VALUES (@username, @picture, ...)
```

... and you should execute the procedure like so:

```
EXEC addlocal 'us1', ..., 123445555.2345
```

To do some more research on this matter, check the following documentation:

- [Variables in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/variables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
- [SQL Server float and real data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
- [Difference between numeric, float and decimal in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056323/difference-between-numeric-float-and-decimal-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

Change your Insert line like this:

```
Insert into DataImage values(@username,@picture,@name,@zone,@category,@coment,@altitude,@longitude)
```