# What should I keep as datatype in Informatica for a field that is FLOAT in source and target?

Tags: sql-server, informatica, sqldatatypes

I have a field with `FLOAT(53)` datatype in SQL Server. Upon importing it in Informatica, it becomes `FLOAT(15)`.

What datatype I should be using to get max possible accuracy?

Comment: If you want to retain the same "accuracy" then use a `float(53)` again. Though a `float` is inherently an inaccurate data type to start.

Comment: Informatica does not allow to change precision and scale for Float data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, a bunch of issues here.

1. Check this [doc](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-4-0/designer-guide/datatype-reference/transformation-data-types.html) to learn about the available data types in Informatica
2. If you want "max possible accuracy" you should use DECIMAL :) FLOAT (even Double) - is not a precise data type. It allows large numbers, it allows fractions - but it's not precise. In fact it's impossible to represent 0.1! :)
3. If you'll use DECIMAL, you'll have the precise number as long as it won't exceed 15 digits. For a larger numbers you will end up with DOUBLE anyway, unless...
4. You enable `HIGH PRECISION` in your session properties. Then you will keep using precise DECIMAL numbers up to 38 digits.
5. If you'll exceed 38 digits, you will end up with non-precise DOUBLE anyway. Yup - even with `HIGH PRECISION` enabled - check [this doc](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/data-services/10-2/developer-tool-guide/data-type-reference/transformation-data-types/decimal-and-double-data-types/decimal-and-double-values-in-calculations.html).

In your case I presume you should use `DOUBLE` - the `FLOAT` in your SQL Server is not a precise type anyway.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7158770/2834065) is also a great summary on the issue.