# Why does SSMS round results?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ssms

I have a table with field `Latitude` of `real` datatype.

When I query it from SQL Server Management Studio, I get the following:

```
select Latitude from Location where ID = 123
```

[image]

As you can see a value of `26.09418` is returned.  However, if I write a simple console in .NET and retrieve the data from the database, it returns `26.094183`.  It brings back an additional significant number.

Why the mismatch?  Is there a way to stop SSMS from doing it?

For reference, here is the c# code to retrieve the data (using Dapper):

```
string sql = "select Latitude from Location where ID = 123";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(conn)) {
    var location = connection.QueryFirst<Location>(sql);
    Console.WriteLine(location.Latitude);
}

class Location { public Single Latitude { get; set; } }
```

Comment: Could not reproduce.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhzCw.png.

Comment: Common issue with REAL and/or FLOAT.   Consider a DECIMAL with a fixed precision.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056323/difference-between-numeric-float-and-decimal-in-sql-server  and Just for Fun:  https://xkcd.com/2170/

Comment: @RobertHarvey If I run `Str(Latitude,20,16)`, i get  `26.0941829681396480` - which is the true representation of what's in the DB (based on the link in @Rafael's answer).  What do you have?

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to store your data either with the precise `decimal` data type for a known scale and precision, or use `float`.

Saying that, you can workaround it and get your desired output in SSMS simply using `str`

```
create table t(x real)
insert into t values(26.094183)

select * from t
```

> 26.09418

```
select Str(x,9,6) from t
```

> 26.094183

Comment: That's the problem - the data type and the storage mechanism is out of my hands.

Answer (score 1):

The `REAL` type is treated as a `FLOAT(24)`.

> The FLOAT(24) datatype, or smaller, reacts the same way. The first thing to remember when experimenting with floating point numbers in SQL Server is that SSMS renders a floating point number in a way that disguises small differences

[Found in red-gate.com - Calculations using the REAL datatype (single precision)](https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/sql-prompt/the-dangers-of-using-float-or-real-datatypes)