# Get data from Sqlserver(Type float) to double C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, double

When I get data from `SQL server` to `EntityFramework C#`.
My `SQL server` has column:

```
Mycolumn(float, not null)(8 byte);
```

C# model mapping:

```
public double MyColumn {get; set;}.
```

The `SQL server` saves data: 1.8(float, not null), and when I get it with `dapper` or `EntityFramework`,
the column `C#` return 1.79999995231628. I don't understand.

Can who help me get that = 1.8 in `C#`.
Thank you very much and have a nice day.

lovenco

Comment: This is what happens when you use floating point values. Why not use a precise data type instead? Or do you actually need floating point values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `Decimal` data type in `SQL Server` which is precise.

Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: has  the decimal data type in SQL Server resource consuming with float ? 
Thank for your confirm.

Comment: @NguyenLam Read the answer of Iman and you will find the answer to this question + more.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056323/difference-between-numeric-float-and-decimal-in-sql-server