# Difference between DECIMAL and NUMERIC

Tags: sql, types, decimal, numeric

What's the difference between the SQL datatype `NUMERIC` and `DECIMAL` ?
If databases treat these differently, I'd like to know how for at least:

- SQL Server
- Oracle
- Db/2
- MySQL
- PostgreSQL

Furthermore, are there any differences in how database drivers interpret these types?

Answer (score 50):

They are the same for almost all purposes.

At one time different vendors used different names (`NUMERIC`/`DECIMAL`) for almost the same thing. SQL-92 made them the same with one minor difference which can be vendor specific:

`NUMERIC` must be exactly as precise as it is defined — so if you define 4 decimal places to the left of the decimal point and 4 decimal places to the right of it, the DB must always store 4 + 4 decimal places, no more, no less.

`DECIMAL` is free to allow higher numbers if that's easier to implement. This means that the database can actually store more digits than specified (due to the behind-the-scenes storage having space for extra digits). This means the database might allow storing `12345.0000` in the above example of 4 + 4 decimal places, but storing `1.00005` is still not allowed if doing so could affect any future calculations.

Most current database systems treat `DECIMAL` and `NUMERIC` either as perfect synonyms, or as two distinct types with exactly the same behavior.  If the types are considered distinct at all, you might not be able to define a foreign key constrain on a `DECIMAL` column referencing a `NUMERIC` column or vice versa.

Comment: is the decimal/numeric thing not the other way around? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759401/is-there-any-difference-between-decimal-and-numeric-in-ms-sql/759606#759606

Comment: Edited to *be* "the other way around", for clarity; I think David's strikethroughs were more confusing than helpful.

Answer (score 11):

They are synonyms, no difference at all.

At least <strike>on SQL Server</strike> in the ANSI SQL standards.
This [SO answer shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759401/is-there-any-difference-between-decimal-and-numeric-in-ms-sql/759606#759606) some difference in ANSI but I suspect in implementation they are the same

Answer (score 6):

**Postgres:** **No difference**

in [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html) description in table 8.1 looks same, yet it is not explained why it is mentioned separately, so 
according to Tom Lane [post](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20211.1325269672@sss.pgh.pa.us)

> There isn't any difference, in
>   Postgres.  There are two type names because the SQL standard requires
>   us to accept both names.  In a quick look in the standard it appears
>   that the only difference is this:
>
> ```
>      17)NUMERIC specifies the data type exact numeric, with the decimal
>         precision and scale specified by the <precision> and <scale>.
>
>      18)DECIMAL specifies the data type exact numeric, with the decimal
>         scale specified by the <scale> and the implementation-defined
>         decimal precision equal to or greater than the value of the
>         specified <precision>.
> ```
>
> ie, for DECIMAL the implementation is allowed to allow more digits
>   than requested to the left of the decimal point.  Postgres doesn't
>   exercise that freedom so there's no difference between these types for
>   us.
>
> ```
>       regards, tom lane
> ```

also a page lower [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html) state clearly, that

> The types decimal and numeric are equivalent. Both types are part of
>   the SQL standard.

and also at [aliases table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype.html) `decimal [ (p, s) ]` is mentioned as alias for `numeric [ (p, s) ]`

Answer (score 3):

They are actually equivalent, but they are independent types, and not technically synonyms, like ROWVERSION and TIMESTAMP - though they may have been referred to as synonyms in the documentation at one time. That is a slightly different meaning of synonym (e.g. they are indistinguishable except in name, not one is an alias for the other). Ironic, right?

What I interpret from the wording in MSDN is actually:
**These types are identical, they just have different names.**

Other than the type_id values, everything here is identical:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.types WHERE name IN (N'numeric', N'decimal');
```

I have absolutely no knowledge of any behavioral differences between the two, and going back to SQL Server 6.5, have always treated them as 100% interchangeable.

```
for DECIMAL(18,2) and NUMERIC(18,2)? Assigning one to the other is technically a "conversion"?
```

Only if you do so explicitly. You can prove this easily by creating a table and then inspecting the query plan for queries that perform explicit or - you might expect - implicit conversions. Here's a simple table:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NumDec]
(
    [num] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [dec] [decimal](18, 0) NULL
);
```

Now run these queries and capture the plan:

```
DECLARE @num NUMERIC(18,0);
DECLARE @dec DECIMAL(18,0);

    SELECT 
      CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,0), [num]), -- conversion
      CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,0), [dec])  -- conversion
    FROM dbo.NumDec
    UNION ALL SELECT [num],[dec] 
      FROM dbo.NumDec WHERE [num] = @dec  -- no conversion
    UNION ALL SELECT [num],[dec] 
      FROM dbo.NumDec WHERE [dec] = @num; -- no conversion
```

we have explicit conversions where we asked for them, but no explicit conversions where we might have expected them. Seems the optimizer is treating them as interchangeable, too.

Personally, I prefer to use the term DECIMAL just because it's much more accurate and descriptive. BIT is "numeric" too.