# what is the difference between decimal and numeric data type in postgresql

Tags: postgresql-9.1

what is the difference between decimal data type and numeric datatype in postgresql  ? I do not find any difference in manual.

Comment: You can follow the links given below:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841915/difference-betweeen-decimal-and-numeric

Answer (score 4):

There is **no** difference in PostgreSQL. [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL)

> The types `decimal` and `numeric` are equivalent. Both types are part of the SQL standard.

Answer (score 2):

Quoted from: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20211.1325269672@sss.pgh.pa.us

> There isn't any difference, in Postgres.  There are two type names
>   because the SQL standard requires us to accept both names.  In a quick
>   look in the standard it appears that the only difference is this:
>
> ```
>      17)NUMERIC specifies the data type exact numeric, with the decimal
>         precision and scale specified by the <precision> and <scale>.
>
>      18)DECIMAL specifies the data type exact numeric, with the decimal
>         scale specified by the <scale> and the implementation-defined
>         decimal precision equal to or greater than the value of the
>         specified <precision>.
> ```
>
> ie, for DECIMAL the implementation is allowed to allow more digits
>   than requested to the left of the decimal point.  Postgres doesn't
>   exercise that freedom so there's no difference between these types for
>   us.
>
> ```
>       regards, tom lane
> ```