# Difference between Numeric and Decimal in SQL

Tags: sql, sqldatatypes

What's the difference between numeric[(p[,s])] and decimal[(p[,s])] as SQL datatype?

Comment: Try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841915/difference-between-decimal-and-numeric

Answer (score 0):

NUMERIC(p, s) takes two arguments: precision (p) and scale (s). Numeric datatype enforces the exact precision and scale that you have specified.

On other side, DECIMAL(p, s) also takes the same two arguments. However, with the DECIMAL data type, the precision can be greater than the value you have supplied. Thus, this data type can provide you with more flexibility.