# SQL LEETCODE 1661. Average Time of Process per Machine

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
Example 1:

Input: 
Activity table:
+------------+------------+---------------+-----------+
| machine_id | process_id | activity_type | timestamp |
+------------+------------+---------------+-----------+
| 0          | 0          | start         | 0.712     |
| 0          | 0          | end           | 1.520     |
| 0          | 1          | start         | 3.140     |
| 0          | 1          | end           | 4.120     |
| 1          | 0          | start         | 0.550     |
| 1          | 0          | end           | 1.550     |
| 1          | 1          | start         | 0.430     |
| 1          | 1          | end           | 1.420     |
| 2          | 0          | start         | 4.100     |
| 2          | 0          | end           | 4.512     |
| 2          | 1          | start         | 2.500     |
| 2          | 1          | end           | 5.000     |
+------------+------------+---------------+-----------+
Output: 
+------------+-----------------+
| machine_id | processing_time |
+------------+-----------------+
| 0          | 0.894           |
| 1          | 0.995           |
| 2          | 1.456           |
+------------+-----------------+
Explanation: 
There are 3 machines running 2 processes each.
Machine 0's average time is ((1.520 - 0.712) + (4.120 - 3.140)) / 2 = 0.894
Machine 1's average time is ((1.550 - 0.550) + (1.420 - 0.430)) / 2 = 0.995
Machine 2's average time is ((4.512 - 4.100) + (5.000 - 2.500)) / 2 = 1.456
```

```
select 
   a1.machine_id, 
   ROUND(AVG(a2.timestamp - a1.timestamp),3) as processing_time 
from Activity a1
INNER JOIN Activity a2
ON a1.process_id = a2.process_id
WHERE a2.activity_type = 'end' 
  AND a1.activity_type = 'start' 
  and a1.process_id = a2.process_id 
  and  a1.machine_id = a2.machine_id
GROUP BY a1.machine_id
```

My solution was accepted without ROUND, I don't have any idea why I am getting this error

> "function `round(double precision, integer) does your text not exist LINE 2: select a1.machine_id,(SELECT ROUND(AVG(a2.timestamp - a1.tim... ^ HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts."`

Also, I want to mention this answer was accepted in MySQL, but it is not working on PostgreSQL

Comment: Please could you edit your question and add some simple data and the expected output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No function matches the given name and argument types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24751372/no-function-matches-the-given-name-and-argument-types)

Comment: Can you share the DDL of the table `Activity` ?

Comment: "does your text not exist"?  Surely that error message doesn't really say that and got mangled during posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter given to [ROUND](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/functions-math.html#:%7E:text=round%20to%20nearest%20integer) should not be a float.

`select round((5.0/3)::float,3);`  Will fail, and

`select round((5.0/3)::decimal,3);` Will produce the expected `1.667`.

For applying this to your query see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/KuplyIy6)

P.S.  Instead of `decimal` you could have used `numeric`, see: [Postgres: No difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40489965/724039), which explains that there is no diffence for these two types in postgresql.