# ADO VBA type for SQL decimal?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I have some fields in a SQL table which are type decimal(x,y). In the VBA how do I represent these in the ADO parameters for a stored procedure argument? For example, a varchar would be declared using adVarChar:

```
Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("@ColumnX", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this page:

- [ADO Data Types](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/ado_datatypes.asp)

The two data types you may be interested in are `adDecimal` and `adNumeric`. The following post describes the difference between the two:

- [sqldatatypes - Is there any difference between DECIMAL and NUMERIC in SQL Server? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759401/is-there-any-difference-between-decimal-and-numeric-in-sql-server)

Here is an example: http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=149631

Comment: According to http://www.w3schools.com/ado/met_comm_createparameter.asp, to set the length for variable length data types, use the size parameter of the CreateParameter method.