# Why is Django DecimalField attribute `max_digits` non-optional?

Tags: django, django-models

```
CommandError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
(fields.E132) DecimalFields must define a 'max_digits' attribute.
```

Is there a technical reason why `max_digits` is a required attribute for Django's model field `DecimalField`?

The docs say it used Python's `[decimal][1]` module, but python object type doesn't seem to be bothered at all by anything to do with the absolute number of digits of the decimal object.

Maybe there's an opaque ORM reason?

`FloatFields` (against which `DecimalFields` are compared) don't require you to predetermine the number of digits so why decimals?

I know this small additional attribute shouldn't bother me but for some reason it's seemed unnecessary to me ever since the first time I used this field type.

Answer (score 1):

It's required by the database (not the ORM). SQL `decimal` columns are declared with both precision (total number of significant digits) and scale (number of digits to the right of the decimal point).

See for instance the formal grammar quoted at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/759606/2337736